# Push a View from popOver in ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uipopovercontroller

I open a popOver with a view(DetailView) in a view(MapView). it works fine.

But in my detail view has a button(feedback).so i want to push the another view(feedbackform)on btton clicked.

I tried but nothing is Happened.

**Can i push the view inside the popover?**

My code is as follow:

```
// MapView.m

detailsView *popUp=[[detailsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"detailsView_ipad" bundle:nil];


        popView = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popUp];

        popView.delegate =self;

        [popView setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(600, 500)];

 [popView presentPopoverFromRect:control.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

}  


//Detailview.m

-(IBAction)openFeedbackForm:(id)sender {

fbView = [[deatailsFeedback alloc]
                  initWithNibName:@"deatailsFeedback_ipad" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:fbView animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Put a navigation controller as your popover base view controller. I think you can do that ok. So detailsView would be the root of a uinavigationcontroller

Comment: can you post some code??

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this your detailsView should be a Navigation controller with a root controller to the original detailsView.

This way when you pop the navigationController, you can perform push from your detailsView and that would only affect the popOver view

```
    detailsView *popUpView=[[detailsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"detailsView_ipad" bundle:nil];

    UINavigationController *popUpNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:popUpView];    

    popView = [[UIPopoverController alloc]initWithContentViewController:popUpNavController];

    popView.delegate =self;

    [popView setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(600, 500)];

    [popView presentPopoverFromRect:control.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

}


//Detailview.m

-(IBAction)openFeedbackForm:(id)sender {

    fbView = [[deatailsFeedback alloc]
              initWithNibName:@"deatailsFeedback_ipad" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:fbView animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, openFeedForm IBAction method is in Detailview.m?
Meaning the first part of the code is in a different class than the one at the bottom?

If so, since Detailview itself is not in a navigationController, it will not push anything to its non-existant navigation controller.

What you want to do is have MapView push the new view in its navigationController.

Side note: since you are setting the delegate of the popUp in MapView as (self) the IBAction method should be defined in MapView

(This is assuming my first statement about understanding your code is correct)

Comment: but how can i present popover with navigation controller in map view.

Comment: My suggestion will be, keep your code as it is but instead of calling
'[self.navigationController pushViewController:fbView animated:YES];'
Consider calling the appropriate navigation controller from your appDelegate.
Of course you will need to make this navigation controller accessible by Detailview class
Ideally it should be something like this:
'AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] Delegate];'
'[appDelegate.myNavigationController pushViewController....];'